# Vertically align link within div

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Z3he9/

I've been trying to align the green circle vertically within the white box, but I'm struggling on how it should be approached.

Using `vertical-align: center;` does nothing if applied to the circle.

Can anyone explain how it should be done please, in the most semantically correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Dave Mroz, removing the `display:block` from `.title` should do the trick for you. 
But in order to keep the `.box` element's original dimensions from you fiddle, you should also clear the floats after `.title` and `.number`.

**Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3he9/13/).**

Comment: This doesnt align the green box vertically though : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3he9/12/

Comment: Sorry, i didn't update the fiddle when i posted the answer. Check it again, please.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `display:block` attribute from the `title` class and that should do the trick.

Comment: That doesnt really work with extra content though: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3he9/11/. The green box should be aligned vertically within the white box.

Comment: It definitely does but you've changed your CSS code since the original post.  Try it on your original example and let us know if it's not working.  http://jsfiddle.net/Z3he9/  (Aside: You don't need the vertical align thing above, just the change I first mentioned)

Comment: On my screen that fiddle you posted isn't aligned

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` will not work with floated elements as floats are not within the normal 'flow' of the document. You can use vertical align with `inline` or `inline-block` elements.

```
.title{
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Remove `float: right;` from `.number`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your CSS like this way

```
.box {
background-color: white;
padding: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
border-radius:4px;
height:30px;
}

.title {color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
font-family: myriad-pro, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3he9/10/)